# .NET Assembly.LoadFrom slower when PC is on a particular network

Tags: .net, networking, reflection, verisign

I have a .NET 3.5 C# app that loads signed plugins and searches for items using:

```
var myAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(c:\...\MyPlugin.dll)
Type [] Types = myAssembly.GetTypes();
```

When the PC is disconnected from or on most networks, these commands complete in milliseconds. But when the PC is connected to a particular user's network, they take 30 seconds each.

User reports the delay is gone when using

```
<generatePublisherEvidence enabled="false"/>
```

and wants to know why this works. The existing articles I've found imply that fix is really for when you are offline, but in this case the delay is not observed while offline; only when connected to a specific network.

Wireshark confirms .NET Runtime is trying to access the internet to contact Verisign and it's timing out. The user intended to configure their network to not have internet access. So now the question seems to be: How might the user have improperly configured their network, resulting in connected machines acting as if they have access to the internet even though they really don't?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766914/disabling-certificate-revocation-checking-for-an-application-on-windows

Comment: @HansPassant Interesting. In that question, what is working for me isn't working for the OP, and I think what is working for him (although he doesn't like it) is what I've been looking for : )  I'll have the user give it a try.